# java - convert bytes to integer - why AND each byte with 0xff?

Tags: java, math, byte, bit

What is the difference between:

```
int n = (b1 & 0xff) << 24 | (b2 & 0xff) << 16 | (b3 & 0xff) << 8 | b4 & 0xff
```

and

```
int n = b1 << 24 | b2 << 16 | b3 << 8 | b4
```

? Why should we `AND` each byte with `255`?

Comment: To make the program more safe?

Comment: Can you explain why? How does the and make it more safe?

Comment: Are these definitely `byte` types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume types of `b1`, `b2`, `b3` and `b4` are `byte`.

In this case, their values will be sign extended and if they are negative, the result will be wrong if AND isn't used.

Demo:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte a = (byte)128;
        int x1 = a << 8;
        int x2 = (a & 0xff) << 8;
        System.out.println(x1);
        System.out.println(x2);
    }
}
```

[Output](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UodiZtuOfzSzGFJO):

```
-32768
32768
```

Answer (score 4):

First you need to understand that `b1 <<< 24` expects the `a` operand to be of type `int` or `long`.  So, if `b1` is a `byte`, Java will convert it to an `int` before the shift takes place.

That conversion happens by mapping each `byte` value into the corresponding `int` value.  The problem is that `byte` is a *signed* type, which means that the possible values are `-128` through to `+127`.  Therefore, when you convert a `byte` with a negative value, you will get an `int` with a negative value; e.g. the byte `11111111` (binary) which is `-1`  becomes  `11111111111111111111111111111111` (binary) which is also `-1`.

Those leading ones are the result of sign extension, and we do NOT want them if we are about to shift them and combine them in a bitwise fashion.

Hence, you will often see a byte being masked with `0xff` to remove the (unwanted) results of sign extension after the conversion.   For example

```
    11111111111111111111111111101110  &
    00000000000000000000000011111111
```

gives

```
    00000000000000000000000011101110
```